# Selenium, Arquillian, Eclipse: trying to make test wait until the page is fully loaded

Tags: java, selenium, junit, jboss, jboss-arquillian

this is my first time posting here. It's been just a couple of days since I started to use Selenium with Arquillian to test our website... soo please be patient because I still lack a lot of knowledge...

I'm trying to make a login-test by typing in four different combination of user name and password. Three of these are not correct, the website should show an error message when these user name and password are submitted. The test should check if the error message is really shown. Please note that the error message is just a text box in the same website (not a pop-up window or something like that...)

Before entering the next user name/password combination, I would like to refresh the website first. Otherwise the test will always detect the error message from the previous entry. The problem is that the test just stops after submitting the first user name/password and refreshing the page. In JUnit I got this error message: "org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: "Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up".

I am guessing that after refreshing the test should wait some seconds until the page is fully loaded..? But if I use something like "fluentWait" with "findElement(By.id("user_name"))". The test would continue running (it won't wait) because both sessions are the same website (before refresh and after refresh) and the id "user_name" is of course always there...

I would be really grateful for any help :)

```
package org.xxyy.uitest;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.jboss.arquillian.drone.api.annotation.Drone;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class LoginTest {

    static String baseUrl;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Drone
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        baseUrl = "http://team-xxyy.intern/";
    }

    @Before
    public void beforeTest() throws Exception {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseUrl + "xxyy/login.html");
    }

    @Test
    public void fehlLogin1() throws Exception {


        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("user_name"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("user_password"));

        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys("blume");
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys("homersimpson");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_submit")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        verifyLoginInfo("blume", "homersimpson");

    }

    @Test
    public void fehlLogin2() throws Exception {


        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("user_name"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("user_password"));

        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys("blume");
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys("jill");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_submit")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        verifyLoginInfo("blume", "jill");

    }

    @Test
    public void fehlLogin3() throws Exception {

        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("user_name"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("user_password"));

        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys("jack");
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys("homersimpson");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_submit")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        verifyLoginInfo("jack", "homersimpson");

    }

    @Test
    public void fehlLogin4() throws Exception {


        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("user_name"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("user_password"));

        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys("jack");
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys("jill");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_submit")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        verifyLoginInfo("jack", "jill");

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }

    private void verifyLoginInfo(String user_name, String user_password) {

        if (user_name.equals("jack")
                && user_password.equals("jill")
                && driver.getCurrentUrl().startsWith(
                        "https://global.something.com/login/123456789/")) {
            System.out
                    .println("XXYY bitte manuell einloggen. Test wird abgebrochen");
            return;

        }

        if (user_name.equals("jack") && user_password.equals("jill")) {

            if (isForwardSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println("Eingabe: Username = " + user_name
                        + ", Passwort = " + user_password);
                System.out.println("Korrekt-Login: Erfolgreich!");
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Eingabe: Username = " + user_name
                        + ", Passwort = " + user_password);
                System.out
                        .println("Korrekt-Login: Trotz korrekter Benutzername und Passwort ist Login fehlgeschlagen.");
                return;
            }
        }

        if (isAlertPresent()) {
            System.out.println("Eingabe: Username = " + user_name
                    + ", Passwort = " + user_password);
            System.out.println("Fehl-Login: Erfolgreich!");
            return;

        } else {
            System.out.println("Eingabe: Username = " + user_name
                    + ", Passwort = " + user_password);
            System.out
                    .println("Fehl-Login: Fehlermeldung wird nicht angezeigt.");
            return;

        }

    }

    private boolean isAlertPresent() {
        try {
            assertEquals(
                    "Der Benutzername oder das Passwort sind nicht korrekt. Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.",
                    driver.findElement(
                            By.cssSelector("#password-message > span.message"))
                            .getText());
            return true;
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean isForwardSuccessful() {
        try {
            assertEquals(
                    "http://team-xxyy.intern/xxyy/index.html",
                    driver.getCurrentUrl());
            return true;
        } catch (Error e) {
            verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.xxyy.uitest</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxyy-ui-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>xxyy-ui-test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- 20131112 die beiden Zeilen unten wurden neu hinzugefügt von "https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Drone" -->
        <version.org.jboss.arquillian>1.1.1.Final</version.org.jboss.arquillian>
        <version.org.jboss.arquillian.drone>1.2.0.CR1</version.org.jboss.arquillian.drone>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-drone-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian.drone}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- 20131113 Version hab ich erstmal rauskommentiert -->
                <!--  version2.3.2version-->
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-drone-impl</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 20131112 ab hier neu hinzugefügt von "https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Drone" -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain</artifactId>
            <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian.drone}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- bis hier -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-drone-selenium</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-drone-selenium-server</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                    <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.4</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-glassfish-embedded</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
                    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-jbossas-managed</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

**arquillian.xml**

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.com/arquillian" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <extension qualifier="webdriver">
        <property name="browser">firefox</property>
    </extension>

</arquillian>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, few comments to your code

- `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` - you should never instantiate driver by yourself, `@Drone` will do that for you
- you should split your test into 4 methods (you are testing 4 test cases, right?) and introduce method annotated with `@Before` which can refresh the page between tests (or call `driver.get("baseUrl + "xxyy/login.html")` - this will make your code be much more concise and readable
- you can also pull out the contents of test methods and put it in some util method, most of the code is repeating inside every test so some refactoring would be nice here:)

Try it like that and see what happens:)

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying so fast! I tried implementing the changes one after the other. First, I just got rid of the "driver = new FirefoxDriver();" and I noticed that the test just kept on going even after the right user name/password is submitted. When I explicitly instantiate the driver (firefox) the test actually stopped after the right user name/password and the browser has been forward to the main page (index)

Comment: ..and I can't seem to use @BeforeMethod. I get "BeforeMethod" can not be resolved to a type" in Eclipse

Comment: Like I said, it's difficult to tell what is wrong before you split your code into multiple tests. But it's definitely wrong to instantiate driver by yourself

Comment: I've separated my code into 4 tests and run the test class again. Somehow only the first test is successfully executed..after that the test stopped and I got this error message in JUnit: "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Session is closed". My test code looks like this now...

Comment: Do you have browser property in arquillian.xml? https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQGRA2/Using+Drone

Comment: I've uploaded my pom.xml and Arquillian.xml (see 1st post..) I created the pom based on the arquillian tutorial on their webpage...

Comment: UPDATE: it's working!!! I just changed After to AfterClass soo it will only be executed when all tests are through.. Thank you very much!!! Would you mind looking at my login test again just in case there are still some parts need to be improved..? Again, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome:)See my edit for other comment...And if my answer was helpful then would be nice if you were accept or upvote it:)